# Bind to windows's Icon contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, contextmenu

I'm working on a WPF project where i have to restyle the all window - that means hiding the chrome and creating my own styleable titlebar.

I now have my own titlebar with icon, title, custom system buttons (including a ? button), am placing finishing touches on resizing the window with the border grips and responding properly to the values in ResizeMode and WindowStyle, but i still need one more thing to make it right - a regular window has a context menu in the icon. By ths i mean obviously the menu that shows when you right click the window icon.

Can i bind the  system's context menu from the original window icon to my icon or do i really need to rebuild it? I can easylly create my own but some end users might have installed software that add options to this menu and i'd rather not cut their options